# Access components created on runtime, and add actionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt

in my code i am creating components on runtime, like JTextField and JButton, and I want to add actionListener to JButton created during execution of program.
Using following code I am only getting static components, but not new components created on runtime.

```
static public <T extends Component> T getComponentByName(Window window, String name) {

    // loop through all of the class fields on that form
    for (Field field : window.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

        try {
            // let us look at private fields, please
            field.setAccessible(true);

            // compare the variable name to the name passed in
            if (name.equals(field.getName())) {

                // get a potential match (assuming correct &lt;T&gt;ype)
                final Object potentialMatch = field.get(window);

                // cast and return the component
                return (T) potentialMatch;
            }

        } catch (SecurityException ex) {

        } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {

        } catch(IllegalAccessException ex) {

            // ignore exceptions
        }

    }

    // no match found
    return null;
}
```

In a test code block I am trying to get components like following

```
JLabel tt = new JLabel("testing");
this.jPanel_MainWrap.add(tt);
tt.setBounds(20,50,100,30);
JLabel txt = Awt1.getComponentByName(this, "jLabel1");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error :" + txt.getText(), "InfoBox: ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: please why ....................

Comment: What do you try to achive with reflection and your code?

Comment: I am actually fetching data from database and displaying in rows, and I want to add button that will get that record and perform some operations like adding record in other table which is linked with this record.

Comment: There are few other tasks that I want to perform like creating different forms.

Comment: The extra records might better be handled by a `JTable`. New forms by a `CardLayout`..

Comment: agree with JTable, CardLayout instead of hunting for Top-Level Contianers

Comment: I am actually creating list of pending payments against orders.
I've two tables (Orders and Payments) orders contains Total cost and Payments contains payments made against that order.
In this table I want to add a button to add payment against all orders that have outstanding amount.
Like in C# we use gridView control to achieve this, but I am unable to find such solution in JTable. That is why I am trying to create my own Table.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the components using window.getComponents().